# Why the name Model View ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

It is very obvious that Model never going to interact with View directly, as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx) said. So in the name (**Model View ViewModel**), why View came after Model. Is it should be **Model ViewModel View** (MVMV). Is there any significance in the name or is it just for easy pronunciation.

Comment: Probably as counterpart to the already existing "Model View Controller".